# How can I reverse the order of a discrete scale within an individual ggplot library function without explicitly referencing the data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have several different parameters to take into consideration for making a plot, and I often do something like this:

```
if (condition){
  flip = coord_flip()
  fill = scale_fill_manual(colors=rainbow(5))
}
else{
  flip = NULL
  fill = brewer.pal(5, 'Dark2')
}

ggplot(data, aes(x=variable, fill=class)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  flip + 
  fill
```

This allows me to consolidate a large number of ggplot combinatorics into one function call.

There exists a `scale_x_reverse()` as well as a `scale_x_continuous(trans="reverse")` function call that can change the displayed order of a variable, but these methods do not work in the most recent version.

This would be very convenient to use, since I often prefer to reverse the order of a factor if using `coord_flip()`, so that the most important information is at the top.

edit:

Here is some data (and the library imports) that you can use:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
data = data.frame(variable=rep(letters[1:5], each=10), 
       class=toupper(letters)[sample(1:5, 50, replace=T) )

modifier = NULL

ggplot(data, aes(x=variable, fill=class)) + geom_bar() + modifier
```

Image without x-axis releveling:

[image]

Of course this is a trivial example, and `fct_rev` from the `forcats` library could easily modify this, although I have more complicated ones that have multiple `aes()` blocks within multiple types of plots. My goal here is to accomplish something without having to directly modify the data. That would mean setting `modifier` to some object that would control this.

Comment: The curly braces don't match up.

Comment: It's a little bit difficult to follow your thoughts since your example is not reproducible... could you make it that?

Comment: Does `library(forcats); aes(x=fct_rev(variable), fill=class))` do what you're looking for?

Comment: Perhaps `rev()` ?

Comment: I like that function `fct_rev` (haven't seen it before), although I would prefer to keep the changes out of any `aes()` statements and avoid referencing the variable itself.